# how to convert from list<object[]> to a specific a form

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm working with spring boot and angular have an issue I'm selecting from two tables that make my query return list<object[]>

```
 @Query(value = "select count(*)  , p.des_prod   from produit p , pack k ,dis d WHERE p.cod_prod = k.cod_prod and k.cod_dist=d.cd_dist and adresse =:adresse group by p.des_prod", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object>  query(@Param("adresse") String adresse);
```

that query returns something like that

```
 [
    [
        6,
        "article 1 "
    ],
[
     8,
    "article2 "
    ]
```

but in the front (angular) I need it in a form like that

```
[{
       name: "article 1 ",
        y : 6

},
{
   name: "article2 ",
    y : 8
}]
```

Comment: You can create a new bean (the way the front end needs it) and covert each `Object[]` to that bean and share it's list as the response.

Comment: I'm not allowed to add other classes in the architecture

Comment: Then you'll have to convert that `Object[]` data to a JSON String.

Comment: i'd tried to but i didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change return from `List<Object>` to `List<Object[]>` in your query method.
2. Use Collectors toList(). Note: This is an example code.

   ```
       List<Object[]> result = spotifyRepository.query();// [["Shawn Mendes", "Senorita","canadian pop",99], ... ],

       List<Object> resultList = result.stream()
       .map(x -> {

           Spotify data= new Spotify();
           data.artistName =x[0].toString();
           data.trackName =x[1].toString();
           data.genre =x[2].toString();
           data.popularity =Integer.valueOf((int) x[3]);

           return data;
       })
       .collect(Collectors.toList());// use resultList in order to get this [{"artistName": "Shawn Mendes","trackName": "Senorita",  "genre": "canadian pop","popularity": 99} , ...]
   ```